# How to install Chinese keyboard with IME suggestions?

Tags: server, keyboard, virtualbox, ibus, input-language

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS VM on virtualbox. After trying multiple ways I am unable to have Chinese keyboard on vm.
(I am using "ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso" for my VM on virtualbox)
.
I have tried following:

```
sudo apt-get install language-pack-zh*  sudo apt-get install chinese*  
sudo apt install ibus-libpinyin  
sudo apt-get install ibus-pinyin  
# set keyboard as chinese
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

But still it types in English.

Comment: yes I am using "ubuntu-20.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso" for my VM on virtualbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Gunnar Hjalmarsson](https://askubuntu.com/users/159370/gunnar-hjalmarsson), just adding on to his answer I have made a descriptive post here.

To get Chinese language IME on Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS

1. Install ibus-libpinyin -

> sudo apt install ibus-libpinyin

2. Go to Settings > Region and Language > click on “+” and add Chinese(Pinyin) to the list
   [image: Settings > Region and Language]
3. Click on setting gear symbol here and it will show “preferences”
   [image: Preferences > General section]
   [image: Preferences > Pinyin mode section]
   [image: Preferences > Dictionary section]
4. Use command “`ibus-setup`” and it will start ibus-daemon
   [image: dialog box after ibus-setup command]

Set these environment variables to keep ibus-daemon running

It will open ibus settings –
[image: ibus-setup General section]

In input-method add “Chinese Intelligent Pinyin” and remove “Chinese Pinyin” if any
[image: ibus-setup Input Method section]
[image: ibus-setup Advanced section]

5. Switch to Chinese language using “super(windows)+space” key, for chinese pinyin it will show IME
   [image: Chinese IME]
6. If you get “Invalid UTF-8” error while typing in Chinese then use command –

> ibus-daemon -drx

Answer (score 1):

Of the commands you mentioned, this one should be sufficient:

```
sudo apt install ibus-libpinyin
```

It pulls ibus (if not already installed) as well as im-config.

Then you should relogin in order to let im-config start ibus-daemon and set the required environment variables.

Next you need to add e.g. *Intelligent Pinyin* to your list of input sources. On a desktop that can be done by opening ibus-setup. Not sure about a server; it depends on whether you have enough programs to open a graphical window.

Finally you should be able to switch to Chinese via the `<Super>Space` shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have installed "ibus-libpinyin". Now can you please clarify following points-->
1)which environment variables to set?
2)I am not getting "intelligent pinyin" in the list of ibus in "Region and Language" setting
3)How to open ibus setup on ubuntu server